# How come no data appears on my line chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, oop, linechart, bootcamp

I am assigned to update my line chart using the object oriented approach:

1. Change the line color to green.
2. Change the marker to a diamond.
3. Change the line width to 2 points.
4. Add a legend for the city of Boston.
5. Add a title and axes labels.
6. Add a y-axis limit.
7. Add grid lines.

For the matlab version the following lines of code are used and they end up producing a line graph with all the necessary info.

```
# Create the plot.
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, marker="*", color="blue", linewidth=2, label='Boston')
# Create labels for the x and y axes.
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Fare($)")
# Set the y limit between 0 and 45.
plt.ylim(0, 45)
# Create a title.
plt.title("PyBer Fare by Month")
# Add a grid.
plt.grid()
# Add the legend.
plt.legend()
```

[image: Line Chart]

This was my attempt at using the object oriented version based on the numbered steps provided above:

```
x_axis = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

y_axis = [10.02, 23.24, 39.20, 35.42, 32.34, 27.04, 43.82, 10.56, 11.85, 27.90, 20.71, 20.09]

# Create the plot.
ax.plot(x_axis,y_axis)

ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis, marker="D", color="green", linewidth=2, label='line')

# Create labels for the x and y axes.
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Fare ($)")

# Set the y limit between 0 and 45.
ax.set_ylim(0,45)

# Create a title.
ax.set_title("PyBer Fare by Month")

# Add a grid.
ax.grid()
ax.legend('Boston')
```

The correct output is supposed to look like this:

[image: Plot 2]

Comment: Are you missing `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`?

Comment: you say *"matlab "* but surely you mean `matplotlib` ?

Comment: @D.L I think they are referring to the pyplot interface as the "matlab" version.

Comment: @jared, possibly.  However, clarity would be helpful. In particular since the example code omits the imported modules which would clarify this.

Comment: @D.L I'm with you. I'm just speculating why they said Matlab (which is probably not helpful...).

Comment: Barring the missing `subplots` call (as BigBen already pointed out), the extra plot call, and the messed up legend (you have it right in the first piece of code), I get the right results (after making the changes and including the imports). So, what's your question

Comment: Data still not appearing. The syntax is identical with the exception of the spacing.

Comment: Please update your post with the entire code (including imports).

Comment: Depending on the environment where you run the code, you might also need `plt.show()` at the end. To nicely fit the labels, `plt.tight_layout()` (just before `plt.show()`) often is helpful. Did you get an error message? Did you get a fully empty plot? With or without empty axes? Which Matplotlib version and which Python environment are you using?

Comment: I'm not receiving an error message. I'm getting a message that says Out[10]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x18e1670e248>

Comment: @jared How do I update my question so I can show you the process from the beginning?

Comment: If you copy the code you posted into a new python script, it won't run because you're missing some things. Edit that script to include every necessary to run and then share that code.