# Why is the data on my updated line chart empty and not producing any output?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

To begin with, I create a line chart with the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

The following cell, I import the matplotlib dependency:

```
# Import dependencies.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The following cell will contain data involving time period

```
# Set the x-axis to a list of strings for each month.
x_axis = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

# Set the y-axis to a list of floats as the total fare in US dollars accumulated for each month.
y_axis = [10.02, 23.24, 39.20, 35.42, 32.34, 27.04, 43.82, 10.56, 11.85, 27.90, 20.71, 20.09]
```

The following line of code will display x and y axis data:

```
# Create the plot
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
```

A normal line graph will appear as a result.

Utilizing the object oriented interface method will include the following code in a new cell:

```
# Create the plot with ax.plt()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
```

You obtain the same result but with a different syntax.

Then I am assigned to enhance my line of code to look like this:

```
# Create the plot with ax.plt()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
```

The output is the same graph without the lines

I update my code to include the following based on the cell above:

```
# Create the plot with ax.plt()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
```

Utilizing the object oriented method results in the following:

```
# Create the plot with ax.plt()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
```

Then I apply the show method if I want to have two or more sets of data to plot:

```
# Create the plot.
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```

Next I am assigned to annotate my ride sharing chart to make it visually appealing:

```
# Create the plot and add a label for the legend.
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, label='Boston')
# Create labels for the x and y axes.
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Fare($)")
# Set the y limit between 0 and 45.
plt.ylim(0, 45)
# Create a title.
plt.title("PyBer Fare by Month")
# Add the legend.
plt.legend()
```

Afterwards, I am updating my code to include new colors, modified width, and a marker for data points. The new cell will look like this:

```
# Create the plot.
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, marker="*", color="blue", linewidth=2, label='Boston')
# Create labels for the x and y axes.
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Fare($)")
# Set the y limit between 0 and 45.
plt.ylim(0, 45)
# Create a title.
plt.title("PyBer Fare by Month")
# Add a grid.
plt.grid()
# Add the legend.
plt.legend()
```

I am tasked with an assignment to update my line chart using the object oriented approach with the following steps:

1. Change the line color to green.
2. Change the marker to a diamond.
3. Change the line width to 2 points.
4. Add a legend for the city of Boston.
5. Add a title and axes labels.
6. Add a y-axis limit.
7. Add grid lines.

Based on the previous cell of code written, it contains a blue line with all the necessary info along with marker points. The outcome of my code this time is supposed to look the exact same except with a different color.

This was my attempt:

```
x_axis = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

y_axis = [10.02, 23.24, 39.20, 35.42, 32.34, 27.04, 43.82, 10.56, 11.85, 27.90, 20.71, 20.09]

# Create the plot.
ax.plot(x_axis,y_axis)

ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis, marker="D", color="green", linewidth=2, label='line')

# Create labels for the x and y axes.
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Fare ($)")

# Set the y limit between 0 and 45.
ax.set_ylim(0,45)

# Create a title.
ax.set_title("PyBer Fare by Month")

# Add a grid.
ax.grid()
ax.legend('Boston')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The problem is, data does not appear. I do not receive an error but no graph is displayed.

The only info I get is something that says

```
<Figure size 640x480 with 0 Axes>
```

Based off the matlab syntax, I replaced each line of code with the object oriented syntax so it appears to be more simplified from my previous attempt. Perhaps I need to include the show method but I could not find any sources for how to type the show syntax using object oriented programming. Nevertheless, no line chart data is appearing as output.

```
# Create the plot.
ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis, marker="D", color="green", linewidth=2, label='Boston')
# Create labels for the x and y axes.
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Fare($)")
# Set the y limit between 0 and 45.
ax.set_ylim(0, 45)
# Create a title.
ax.set_title("PyBer Fare by Month")
# Add a grid.
ax.grid()
# Add the legend.
ax.legend()
```

The only output I am receiving is something saying

```
<matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x2d5cf510808>
```

Comment: What about this question is different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77767166/12131013)?

Comment: I included code from the start so you could possibly identify what is missing. Is that not what you requested?

Comment: My question is why you posted this as a new question rather than editing the original question?

Comment: I tried to locate the edit feature but it didn't appear that I was allowed to edit the question since I believe stack overflow allows you to edit your question once.

Comment: There is no limit on how many times you can edit your own post. We encourage you to update whenever there is something to clarify or explain.

Comment: You need to create `fig` and `ax` *in the same cell that you are using them to plot*.